# Merge multiple files in TFS

Tags: tfs, merge

We're using TFS as version control system for our software. Currently the software has two versions in two separate branches: branch "Version 1.0" and  branch "Version 2.0".
Every fix in "Version 1.0" has to be merged into "Version 2.0". I merge manually from the context menu on the file to be merged.

My problem is that some fixes comprise more than one file located in different folders. Then I have to perform the same action on every file.

Is there a posibility to merge a group of files at once? If not, is there a recomended practice how to perform the merge operation?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have a couple options:

1. If you know the changesets you want to merge (or the changesets you want to avoid merging) you can choose a folder up the structure from the files you want to merge then do the merge by selecting the specific changesets you want. This is a little complicated if you have changesets 2000,2001,2004, 2010 and you want 2001 and 2010. You can only merge consecutive changesets in the list per merge so you would have to merge 2001 then 2010. This is still better than merging many files if you have more files then changeset groups.
2. If you want to merge everything under that folder up to a specific changeset or most recent changeset you can do that in one bulk merge.

In both of these you will still have to resolve issues where a different change was made to the same line in the same file in the source and target branches.